# Configuring and Mounting Micro SD Card in OpenWRT

Tags: filesystems, openwrt, sd-card

The Vocore is a single board computer running OpenWRT. It has very limited internal storage capacity with only ~1MB for storing packages and files. I need additional space for installing Python and other packages. The Vocore also has a Micro SD card slot. When I insert a card, a new entry appears in `/dev` named `mmcblk0`. How can I configure the card to expand the root file system? Thank you.

Comment: Simply mount it anywhere on the VFS. But I assume what you want is the root / file system to be bigger?

Comment: Appearing in dev is already 99% of the problem solved. You partition, format and mount it. Just try to found it the max size of the card the SBC supports.

Comment: @jdwolf You are correct. I've never formatted and managed volumes and filesystems from the terminal. I would like to extend the root file system.

Comment: @www139 On linux generally this is solved with either installing root to the sdcard and using internal as only a boot loader or for initram or using an overlay fs.

Answer (score 1):

Search the OpenWrt wiki and/or forum for `overlay` and/or `extroot`.

—▷ https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/opkg
—▷ https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/extroot_configuration